# How does Mutt decide if an email has been replied to?

Tags: mutt

Mutt places an `r` flag next to emails that I've replied to. However, sometimes it errs, and there is no flag next to an email that I *have* replied to.

`notmuch` correctly identifies the thread. If I move the message from my inbox to "sent" mailbox, `mutt` correctly puts the emails together when sorting by thread.

I checked the incoming mail, and it has this header.

```
Message-Id: <[some_random_numbers]@gmail.com>
```

My reply has the corresponding header.

```
In-Reply-To: <[same_random_numbers]@gmail.com>
```

FWIW Thunderbird is also missing the "replied" icon for this email, although it's correctly threaded.

Why does `mutt` not recognise that the incoming mail has been replied to, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Depends how the emails are stored. There are flags in maildir (in the file name) or in IMAP for that.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The emails are stored in maildir format, synced via IMAP through isync/mbsync. (Does the similar failure in Thunderbird suggest it's IMAP to blame?)

Comment: In `mutt`, I pressed `wr` on the message, to give it the "read" flag. I noticed the maildir file changed from `*:2,S` to `*:2,RS`. Then, the flag also appeared in Thunderbird.

Comment: In IMAP or the failure to synchronise the state between local maildir and IMAP. Have you tried with `offlineimap`?

Comment: `wr` would give it the _replied_ flag (`R`), _read_ is _seen_ (`S`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm not sure what you mean by the first line. However, I've managed to isolate the problem. I think it's a bug in mutt. If I postpone the half-composed email, quit, then resume and send, the flag appears as expected. However, if there is another instance of mutt open at the same time (in the same folder), then the `R` flag doesn't appear. I guess this question is moot… but do you know if there is a way to "correct" all replied flags then?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Oh, sorry, yep I meant "replied", not "read".